# Julia mapping a function that returns a 2 dimensional array to a 3 dimensional array

Tags: function, multidimensional-array, julia

I have a function that returns a 2 dimensional array.
If I `map` this function to a `UnitRange` I get a 1 dimensional array of 2 dimensional arrays.
Is there a neat way collect this to a 3 dimensional array?

```
y = rand(3,3)
f(x) = y * x
map(f, 1:9)
```

This will result in a `9-element Array{Array{Float64},2}` and not a `Array{Float64,3}`.
The same is achieved using a comprehension.

Comment: Or would it alternatively be a better solution to make the function take a `UnitRange` as input and always return a 3 dimensional array?

Comment: `cat(3,map(f,1:9)...)`  is a possibility

Comment: `[i*j for i in y,j=1:9]` is another without defining `f`

Comment: That does yield a 3 dimensional array but the result is still an array of arrays
`9x1x1 Array{Array{Float64,2},3}` instead of a `3x3x9 Array{Float64,3}`

Comment: What Julia version are you using? I have `typeof([i*j for i in y,j=1:9])==Array{Float64,3}` on 0.5 (and same type for `cat` expression)

Comment: Your second comment does return the desired 3 dimensional array for the given case. But in my case the function `f` does not just multiply a scalar by a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Actually the cat expression does work i had missed the ellipsis `...`.
Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cat` function, as per the [Julia documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/arrays/#Base.cat):

> `cat(dims, A...)`
>
> Concatenate the input arrays along the specified
>   dimensions in the iterable dims.

For example, the following con`cat`enates two 2D arrays in the third dimension.

```
julia> A = collect(reshape(1:9, 3, 3));

julia> B = collect(reshape(10:18, 3, 3));

julia> cat(3, A, B)
3×3×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

[:, :, 2] =
 10  13  16
 11  14  17
 12  15  18
```

Applying this to your situation, you can `foldl` across the array of arrays...

```
foldl((A,B) -> cat(3, A, B), map(f, 1:9))
```

For a far cleaner solution, though, you can use the splat (`...`) operator to pass all array results to a single call of the `cat` function.

```
cat(3, map(f, 1:9)...)
```